# Basics of google cloud messaging (GCM) using Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

i want to make a chat application using GCM.
Actually i am new to use GCM.I have read offcial documentation of GCM.
I need to know how to send and recieve data through server if someone can explain me using basic code.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the api has been changed from the previous one and
the below link will help you..

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html